# How to mount a filesystem from a given USB bus:device

Tags: filesystems, mount, usb, android

Recently I bought a new smartphone (with Android). When I connect it to my laptop, the (gui)file manager (PCManFM) recognize it and show me the filesystem at route `gphoto2://[usb:001,003]`. But I can't found it in a terminal (nothing in `/mnt` nor in `/media`). But this is the output of `lsusb`:

```
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:c05a Logitech, Inc. Optical Mouse M90
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 04f2:b1d8 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0fce:0171 Sony Ericsson Mobile Communications AB
```

How can I mount it knowing the bus and device numbers?. (001:003 in this case).
My OS is Debian Wheezy.

The output of the `mount` command:

```
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,relatime,size=10240k,nr_inodes=497357,mode=755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=405696k,mode=755)
/dev/disk/by-uuid/ec90e556-b90e-467c-80b6-bde9048e6686 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,user_xattr,barrier=1,data=ordered)
tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k)
tmpfs on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=2486440k)
rpc_pipefs on /var/lib/nfs/rpc_pipefs type rpc_pipefs (rw,relatime)
```

Comment: What does **mount** command say? See this [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPhoto).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you see the handlers like `gphoto2://` and `smb://` these are special interfaces that the GNOME desktop or whatever file browser you're using is making available to access these devices. In the case of `gphoto2`, the desktop is using the application gphoto2`

#### lsof

The only way I can think to gain access to a mount such as this would be to mount it as you did before using Nautilus or whatever file browser, and then using a tool such as `lsof` to see what files/devices are opened by Nautilus.

```
$ lsof -p $(pgrep nautilus)
```

But if you're having to connect to your phone via `gphoto2` then you're likely not mounting the device a a mass storage device but rather a [PTP - Picture Transfer Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picture_Transfer_Protocol). There's a [Linux FUSE implementation for PTP too](http://www.dankulp.com/ptpfs/).

#### gvfs?

I would also look in your `$HOME` directory for a sub-directory called `.gvfs`. Usually when GNOME or Nautilus are doing the mounting this directory is created as a convenience.

In newer versions of GNOME (3+) this directory has moved and is now here, `/run/user/$UID/gvfs`.

#### Example

```
$ ls -l /run/user/$UID/gvfs/smb-share\:server\=tank\,share\=t 
total 2
drwx------. 1 saml saml    0 Oct 31 09:16 Development
drwx------. 1 saml saml    0 Nov 18 14:52 home
drwx------. 1 saml saml    0 May 14  2013 incoming
...
```

**NOTE:** That's a environment variable `$UID` that is often set in Bash on most modern systems. If it isn't set you can find your user's ID like so:

```
$ id
uid=1000(saml) gid=1000(saml) groups=1000(saml),10(wheel) context=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023
```

Comment: On newer systems, the gvfs mount directory has moved to `/run/user/$UID/gvfs`.

Comment: @cjm - thanks for the correction. I've added it to the A.

Answer (score 2):

Your smartphone's partition is mounted via [gphotofs](http://gphoto.sourceforge.net/doc/manual/using-gphotofs.html), that is based on [FUSE](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/). That's why you don't see it under /mnt and /media.

You can try to mount your partition via:

```
gphotofs /mnt
```

Comment: *"that is based on FUSE. That's why you don't see it under /mnt and /media."* The second part does not necessarily follow from the first. FUSE or fully-kernel-space file system implementation has no bearing on where in the file system tree a file system can be mounted. I'm not familiar with gphotofs but can't see it having such an arbitrary limitation.